# Using GCD Function With Arrays in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

I'm having trouble determining GCD from a dataset. I'm trying to determine the  quantity of items in a box of any given item in a warehouse without physically looking at each item on the shelves.

Here's a sample dataset that I created from sales orders.

```
0   Part1
36  Part1
12  Part1
18  Part1
6   Part1
0   Part1
6   Part1
36  Part1
36  Part1
20  Part2
5   Part2
15  Part2
20  Part2
25  Part2
0   Part2
30  Part2
```

So looking at this I can see that Part1 comes in boxes of 6. Part2 comes in boxes of 5. This is the return I am looking for.

I feel like I'm close with

`=GCD(SUMPRODUCT(--(A$1:A$16),(B$1:B$16=B1)),A1)`

or

```
=GCD(SUMPRODUCT(--(A$1:A$16)*(B$1:B$16=B1)),A1)
```

but it's not quite working.

Basically, I want something like `SUMIF`. A `GCDIF` function where `=GCDIF(range,criteria,[GCD range])`

Is this possible?

Comment: To clarify for other readers and potential answers, are all of the part numbers grouped together as in the question or are they a random list?  Are there relatively few records and is the list static, so you can find group breaks and hard code them in the formula?  Suppose you have only a few records for a part and they happen to be multiples of the same multiple (e.g., box of 5, but the records are 10 and 20).  Will an answer of 10 be good enough?

Comment: The part numbers are grouped together but there are more than 40,000 records so manually finding the group breaks is not an option. We will run into the problem of multiples of the same multiple resulting in a larger estimated box size than actual, but for this exercise the estimate is close enough and any errors can be fixed by the user creating purchase orders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GCD wrapped in an IF in Array Formula to get the GCD for each Part. See the below example.

Sample data is in cells A1:B15.

In C1 put the following formula and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from within the formula bar to create an Array Formula. The formula shall now be enclosed in Curly Braces to indicate that it's an Array Formula.

```
=GCD(IF($B$1:$B$15=B1,$A$1:$A$15,0))
```

Simply drag it down till the intended rows.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**This solution has a different approach. Use of `If` with `CHOOSE` can also find the `GCD` of data range.**

[image]

*Write this formula in Cell `F73` & fill down.*

```
=IF(E73=$E$71,GCD(CHOOSE(1,D$73:D$78,D$79:D$81)),IF(E73=$F$71,GCD(CHOOSE(2,D$73:D$78,D$79:D$81)),GCD($D$82:$D$83)))
```

**Note,** *adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*